# Excel Macro, data written to text file in quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to automate and expedite data processing with Agilix.
The problem i am having is that when the macro, as shown in the code below, surrounds all the written information in quotation marks.
This isn't a problem when I write .txt with it, however i now have to generate a .xml from it and the quotation marks screw it up.

Here is the macro that writes to the .txt

'
Sub DataOutDataIn(REQ As String)
' Sends the raw data out to notepad then returns it reformatted
'

```
'Specify data target location
    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\DataForReturn.txt"
'Open file and export raw data
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Write #1, Range("A10").Value
    Close #1
'Clear data parsing page and extract the reformatted data
    Sheets("Data For Parsing").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\me\Documents\DataForReturn.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "DataForReturn_3"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 3
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = """"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

End Sub
'

Can anyone tell me why it surrounds with quotes and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Write statement with Print